# How to Geocode a list of address into a map in qgis?

Tags: csv, list

I have a list of country and city capitol  on a Excel, and I want to upload them into a map in QGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the MMQGIS plugin and Geocode a CSV file
 [image]

Make sure that your Excel have at list a Country row and to Address rows
[image]

Then save as a "CSV UTF-8 (comma delimited" file, in some Windows you will see only the "comma delimited". [image]

Once you have the file go the Geocode in the MMQGIS, upload the file and fill up the blanks. It's important to save the output file in a predefined folder.
[image]
After you press the "OK" button it will take some time but you have the address on your map. In this case all the word capitols [image]